Dirac sign flip in matter tensor
I'm reviewing P. Dirac "General Theory of Relativity" and there is some non-standard factor that I don't understand the purpose of.
In the book, at 24.4 they present the EFE we all know:
$$ R^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} R = Y^{\mu \nu}. \tag{24.4}$$
However, for some reason, just a few lines below it follows:

"It is convenient to bring in the coefficient $- 8 \pi$ .."

and eq. 24.6 looks now like this:
$$ R^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} R = - 8 \pi Y^{\mu \nu}.\tag{24.6} $$
Question: ...but... Why? in what way is the sign flip convenient? I would naive think this is actually incorrect (as it would imply that all mass and energy is now negative by convention). Why or how is this not an error, and just a matter of convention? Is Dirac actually making all real matter and energy negative by convention by flipping this sign? why is the sign flip just "convenient" and not plainly wrong?

actually the answer is not "opinion-based" at all and is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Sign_convention
I wasn't aware at all about the 3 different sign conventions! Thanks To MTW for keeping things simple

This sign is indeed a convention. It actually has to do with how you define the Ricci tensor. Some authors define it as $R_{ab} = R_{acb}{}^{c}$, but some as $R_{ab} = -R_{acb}{}^{c}$. Flipping the sign of the Ricci tensor flips the sign of the Einstein tensor, and hence adds that sign to the Einstein equations. This is discussed in the back cover of Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler's Gravitation. All authors agree that standard energy densities are positive (up to energy condition violations, which have nothing to do with sign conventions).

I missed that discussion on all these independent conventions from that magnificent tome, here me naively thinking that all sign conventions was just about signatures choices

@UnkemptPanda I wish there was only the signature sign. In most references that is the easiest one to keep track of, but very often the Riemann and Einstein signs are not spelled out explicitly, so you need to pay close attention to them (especially when working with multiple references)
